# NuGet do I need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore if all I need is its provider?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, entity-framework-core, nuget-package

I'm relatively new to NuGet. I plan to make only use of a sqlite database in my project. Using the NuGet Packet Manager I saw that there are several packages related to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

If make use of only sqlite would the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` package suffice or is it also important to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` package?

I feel a bit confused, when should I install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` and vice versa?

Comment: look at the dependencies of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`

Comment: you may take a look at this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referencing a package via *PackageReference*, you automatically get all of it's dependencies as well.

[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/3.0.0) (targeting *.NETStandard 2.1*) depends on [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core/3.0.0), which depends on [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/3.0.0), which eventually depends on [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.0.0) (which now further depends on other packages).

So a *PackageReference* of

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

gets your project not only the top-level package, but also all transitive dependencies as dependency graph - if the *PackageReferences* of those projects in return isn't tagged with `PrivateAssets` to prevent the flow to the parent project, as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

You can review all the assemblies consumed by your project via the *Solution Explorer* of *Visual Studio*:
[image: VisualStudio-SolutionExplorer]

Or alternatively via the *.NET Core CLI* by typing:
`dotnet list package --include-transitive`

```
Project 'Project' has the following package references
   [netcoreapp3.0]:
   Top-level Package                           Requested   Resolved
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite      3.0.0       3.0.0

   Transitive Package                                           Resolved
   > Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core                                 3.0.0
   > Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions                      3.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore                              3.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions                 3.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers                    3.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational                   3.0.0
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core                  3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions                  3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory                        3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration                         3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions            3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder                  3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection                   3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions      3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel                       3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging                               3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions                  3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Options                               3.0.0
   > Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives                            3.0.0
   > SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3                              2.0.0
   > SQLitePCLRaw.core                                          2.0.0
   > SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3                                 2.0.0
   > SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl                        2.0.0
   > System.Collections.Immutable                               1.6.0
   > System.ComponentModel.Annotations                          4.6.0
   > System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource                        4.6.0
   > System.Memory                                              4.5.3
   > System.Text.Json                                           4.6.0
   > System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions                          4.5.2
```

To answer your second question: You may want to just install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` for database provider agnostic class libraries, providing general *Entity Framework Core* functionality.

Comment: Even if you don't use PackageReference, the package manager will automatically add all the required dependencies